# Grouping 2 sets of data into 1 set using the same key

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following 2 set of data and I want to combine it into one whole set (summing one of the column). In this example, only 1 item is shown.

1st set (master table):

```
start_date  |item  
2013-10-01  | 1  
2013-10-15  | 1  
2013-10-25  | 1
```

2nd set (detail table):

```
working_date | item_no | qty  
2013-10-03   |   1     |  2  
2013-10-05   |   1     |  6  
2013-10-18   |   1     |  3  
2013-10-23   |   1     |  4  
2013-10-27   |   1     |  6  
2013-10-28   |   1     |  3
```

Then, I want to group the data in the detail table together with the master table according to the starting date and summing the qty as follow:

Final table (result):

```
starting_date | item_no | total_qty  
2013-10-01    |   1     |   8  
2013-10-15    |   1     |   7  
2013-10-25    |   1     |   9
```

My difficult is that I do not know how to sum the qty by matching the working_date into the starting_date range before summing the qty.

In other words, I need to sum the qty starting from 2013-10-01 to 2013-10-14, 2013-10-15 to 2013-10-24 and 2013-10-25 to 2013-10-31

Comment: Is that not just an inner join and group by item_no, sum by qty?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen. Surely not. he has to match the dates from detail to a range of dates.

Comment: I Couldn't completely follow your question. can you elaborate more on your question "How can I distinguish/put the working_date into the starting_date range before summing the qty?"??

Comment: @FilipeSilva you can inner join on dates and ranges as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each record in detail table, you need to find the nearest previous date from master table. Once you find that, just aggregate on that date.

```
select starting_date, sum(qty)
from (
  select working_date,
         item_no,
         qty,
         (select max(master_table.starting_date)
          from master_table
          where master_table.starting_date <= details_table.working_date
          and master_table.item_no = details_table.item_no
         ) as starting_date
from details_table
  ) as modfied_table
group by starting_date
order by starting_date;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48986/3).

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't totally clear, but this should be enough of an example for you to work with.

```
SELECT master_table.starting_date, 
    details_table.item_no, 
    SUM(details_table.qty)
FROM master_table 
JOIN details_table 
  ON master_table.item_no = details_table.item_no
GROUP BY master_table.starting_date, 
         details_table.item_no
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @startDate Datetime
set @startDate=DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE()) -- set the startdate 2 months before today
declare @endDate Datetime
set @endDate=GETDATE() -- set the ending date equal to current datetime
declare @DaysStep int
set @DaysStep=10 -- set the step from day to the next day equal to 10 days. 
                -- so if today is 12/01/2013 the next day will be 12/11/2013

declare @results table (starting_date Datetime, item_no int, total_qty int)

while @startDate<@endDate
    begin
        insert into @results
        select starting_date, item_no, sum(qty) as total_qty
        from master as m
        inner join detail as d
        on m.item_no=d.item_no
        where startingDate between @starDate and DATEADD(Days, @DaysStep, @startDate)
    @startDate=DATEADD(Days, @DaysStep, @startDate)
    end

select *
from @results
```

I suppose that you usel mssql. Otherwise you should change the above code to your sql dialect. Also you can set the @startDate, @endDate and @DaysStep as you wish.

Comment: sorry, forget to tell. I am using PL/SQL, oracle DB

Comment: @calvinyankf no problem at all! Unfortunately, I have never used an oracle DB. So I don't know its sql dialect. However, I don't think that it would be difficult to transform the above TSQL code to you PL/SQL dialect. In case of any ambiguity, please let me know, in order to explain it to you and make your transformation process without errors.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
SELECT start_date, item_no, sum(qty) as qty 
FROM #mastertable as aa INNER JOIN #detailtable as bb ON aa.item = bb.item_no
WHERE (start_date <= working_date 
    AND working_date < (SELECT TOP 1 start_date FROM #mastertable as innerT WHERE innerT.start_date > aa.start_date))
    OR (working_date >= (SELECT TOP 1 start_date FROM #mastertable as innerT ORDER BY innerT.start_date DESC)
    AND start_date = (SELECT TOP 1 start_date FROM #mastertable as innerT ORDER BY innerT.start_date DESC))
GROUP BY start_date, item_no
ORDER BY start_date
```